# regex issue with matching first occurence

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this regex:

It is meant to return the first occurrence of a colour but keeps returning the last.

```
$string = "Red is a sexy colour. Yellow too. Pink too. Blue too. Green too. Hehe.";

preg_match('/^.*\b(red|green|blue|yellow)\b.*$/i', $string, $colour );

echo $colour[1]; // Should say Red, but returns Green... o.O
```

print_r on $colour shows:

```
Array ( [0] => Red is a sexy colour. Yellow too. Pink too. Blue too. Green too. Hehe.
        [1] => Green )
```

Comment: what `echo $colour[0];` outputs?

Comment: print_r shows: `Array ( [0] => Red is a sexy colour. Yellow too. Pink too. Blue too. Green too. Hehe. [1] => Green )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the filler before your pattern ungreedy, you can also just remove the filling before and after your pattern and the anchors:

```
preg_match('/\b(red|green|blue|yellow)\b/i', $string, $colour);
```

will return the first match.

Answer (score 2):

No, it shouldn't. The point is that regex engine first tries to match the pattern given with as many letters in the source string as it could. It's very greedy by default. )

In other words, the pattern you've specified will try to look for the four color words from the *end* of the string. You can either make it non-greedy (by replacing first `.*` with `.*?`) - or try to reform your pattern completely.

I see a little use for ^ and $ markers, followed by .*, for example, if you're just looking for these words, why don't use something as simple as...

```
/\b(red|green|blue|yellow)\b/
```

Comment: Thank you, actually considered writing detailed explanation why it's better to use that pattern - but given up soon. )

Answer (score 1):

Your `.*` part is greedy, ie. it matches as much as possible before a color name occurs. To change it to non-greedy use `.*?`

```
preg_match('/^.*?\b(red|green|blue|yellow)\b.*$/i', $string, $colour );
```

Comment: Sure enough that fixed it. Can you explain why that was happening?

Comment: 9 minutes before I can tick it. Until then; Have my first born child :)